# Splitting an Excel spreadsheet into different worksheets based on column headers

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 45 columns. Some of the columns contain the same type of information, and I have grouped these columns together under a common column header.

Please see the spreadsheet below for an example.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i9Rr.jpg)

With reference to the example above, I would like to split the spreadsheet into three different worksheets based on the top column headers (not values). Hence, there should be three worksheets called "Primary Info", "Secondary Info" and "More Info", in addition to the original worksheet which contains all the information.

Under each of the new worksheets I want to see all the information related to that specific column header, e.g. the worksheet called "Primary Info" should display all fields for Name, Age and Gender.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Split()
Dim c, i As Integer
    c = 1
Dim ws As Worksheet

Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(1, c) = ""
    Sheet1.Cells(1, c).Select
    i = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Columns.Count + c - 1
    Sheet1.Range(Cells(2, c), Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count, i)).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = Sheet1.Cells(1, c)
    End With
    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    c = i + 1
    Sheet1.Activate
Loop

End  Sub
```